# In Shopify, how do I access a user id (or anonymous id) when the user is not logged in?

Tags: shopify

I know that I can access {{ customer.id }} when the user is logged in but I want to use a unique identifier for the user when they are not logged in? Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged in - `customer` variable is not defined.
So, probably, generate a unique ID and save it in cookies using JS.

Comment: I was afraid that may be the answer.